# How to fix this CLI error in SAS?

Tags: sql-server, sas

I've been getting this error when I try to drop, delete, truncate a table in SQL Server using SAS:

> ERROR: CLI error trying to establish connection: [DataDirect][ODBC SQL
>   Server Wire Protocol driver]Error parsing connect string at 
>          offset 74.

This is the code that's causing it:

```
proc sql;
  connect to odbc(noprompt="Driver={DataDirect 6.1 SQL Server Wire Protocol};99.999.999.99;Port=1433;Database=AAA;Uid=sqluser;Pwd=sqlserverpass;");
    execute (drop table dbo.BBB_SUMMARY) by odbc;
  disconnect from odbc;
quit;
```

Append works okay. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: This may be silly suggestion (but I fell for it not long ago) Does your username have privilage to drop tables?

Comment: I don't think the user name is the problem.  I am using the same user name in SAS and Management Studio.  I can drop and delete in Management Studio but not through SAS.

Comment: how About using the full name?: drop table <database>.dbo.bbb_summary?

Comment: Still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

**"Error parsing connect string at offset 74."** is a pretty big clue.

Presuming 99.999.999.99 in your connection string is the ip address of your SQL Server, you might need to change that to HOST=99.999.999.99.

See [DataDirect docs](http://media.datadirect.com/download/docs/odbc/allodbc/index.html#page/odbc%2FHost_Name_5.html%23wwID0E13NU)

Couldn't speculate why the same seemingly malformed connection string would work for append.